# How to draw Flowchart Summing junction using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

How to draw following symbol using tikz?

And why isn't there a standard package which will have all necessary and commonly used shapes in flowcharts. Even existing flowchart package has very less inventory of shapes.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you think that LaTeX is missing vital functionality then please write a package for it! :)

Comment: Ha ha ha ... OK ;-)

Comment: Apparently, there is no such agreement on necessary and commonly used shapes for flowcharts.

Comment: Isn't that a multiplication junction? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a flow chart a `node` style might be useful:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{FlowChartBlue}{rgb}{.3,.5,.75}
\tikzset{
  summing junction/.style={
    circle,
    draw=FlowChartBlue!50!black,
    fill=FlowChartBlue,
    minimum size=2cm,
    path picture={
      \draw [FlowChartBlue!50!black]
            (path picture bounding box.135) -- (path picture bounding box.315)
            (path picture bounding box.45) -- (path picture bounding box.225);
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [summing junction] (a) at (0,0) {};
\node [summing junction] (b) at (4,2) {};

\draw [-latex] (a) to[bend left] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Just drawing

Another version, following comment. The clue here is that the `+` indicates that the coordinate is relative to the previous coordinate (`(2,2)` in the example).

I don't see how this is better than the above version though, as drawing lines to the circle is more complicated.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue!50] (2,2) circle[radius=1cm]
   +(45:1cm) -- +(225:1cm)
   +(135:1cm) -- +(315:1cm);

\filldraw[fill=blue!50] (4,1) circle[radius=1cm]
   +(45:1cm) -- +(225:1cm)
   +(135:1cm) -- +(315:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Ellipses

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
  summing junction ellipse/.style={
    ellipse,
    draw=blue!50!black,
    fill=blue!50,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw [blue!50!black]
            (path picture bounding box.135) -- (path picture bounding box.315)
            (path picture bounding box.45) -- (path picture bounding box.225);
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue!50] (2,2) circle[x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm]
   +(45:2cm and 1cm) -- +(225:2cm and 1cm)
   +(135:2cm and 1cm) -- +(315:2cm and 1cm);

\filldraw[fill=red!50] (4,-1) circle[x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm]
   +(60:2cm and 1cm) -- +(240:2cm and 1cm)
   +(120:2cm and 1cm) -- +(300:2cm and 1cm);

\node [summing junction ellipse,fill=green!50] at (8,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can it be done without using \tikzset like in native syntax where we draw a circle first and then 'X' using lines. `\draw (2cm,2cm) circle (2cm); and after this code to draw lines. `

Comment: @charlesbell Yes (see update), but I don't see why you would do that.

Comment: I am having little problem while applying same thing with ellipse, is there any thing I can use in place of radius dimension i.e. `1cm`, that will automatically limit length till the arc of ellipse.

Comment: @charlesbell You can specify major and minor axis in polar coordinates, as mentioned in the manual (cf. Heiko's comment on his answer), e.g. `(45:2cm and 1cm)`. See answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote :-(

Answer (score 4):

The symbol can be easily drawn in TikZ using polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{FlowChartBlue}{rgb}{.3,.5,.75}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\Radius{10mm}
    \filldraw[fill=FlowChartBlue]
      (0, 0) circle[radius=\Radius]
      (135:\Radius) -- (315:\Radius)
      (45:\Radius) -- (225:\Radius)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: (135:\Radius) -- (315:\Radius) (45:\Radius) -- (225:\Radius) what does this syntax mean?

Comment: @charlesbell See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) of TikZ: "13.2.1 Canvas, XYZ, and Polar Coordinate Systems".

Answer (score 3):

Not too difficult to draw with MetaPost either, for whom it may interest. Here the code is included in a LuaLaTeX program.

For sophisticated flowcharts with MetaPost, I've heard about the [Metaflow](https://www.utdallas.edu/~hamlen/metaflow.pdf) package, but it's not on CTAN and I have not tried it yet.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    radius := 3cm; path circle; circle = fullcircle scaled 2radius;
    fill circle withcolor .3red + .5green + .75blue; draw circle;
    path diameter; diameter = (left -- right) scaled radius rotated 45;
    draw diameter; draw diameter rotated 90;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]